# Symfony2 , doctrine custom query

Tags: symfony, doctrine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Symfony2 & Doctrine: Create custom SQL-Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12862389/symfony2-doctrine-create-custom-sql-query)

I tried that on my symfony2 project :

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$query = $em->createQuery(
        'SELECT v.voiture,o.offre,m.marque
         FROM FrontOfficeBundle:Voiture v
         INNER JOIN FrontOfficeBundle:OffreSpecial o on o.voiture_id = v.id
         INNER JOIN FrontOfficeBundle:Marque m on m.id = v.marque_id'
    );
$result = $query->getResult();
```

and get  that erreur :

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 122: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_WITH, got 'on'
```

even the SQL query are correcte ! plz help

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `ON` option for your `INNER JOIN`.  The Doctrine Query Language already knows the mapping of your associations because you specified the class `FrontOfficeBundle:Voiture` in your query.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$query = $em->createQuery(
        'SELECT v.voiture,o.offre,m.marque
         FROM FrontOfficeBundle:Voiture v
         INNER JOIN v.offreSpecial o 
         INNER JOIN v.marque m'
    );
$result = $query->getResult();
```